# BitmapListAnimation - how to jump to the selected frame

Tags: delphi, animation, firemonkey

Delphi 10.2 and BitmapListAnimation.

I have a bitmap of 96 frames/Sprites.

How to make a condition that the looped animation from the last frame does not return to first but to 30?

Comment: I created the animation using a BitmapListAnimation. Animation is looped. But i need get:

a)  When the animation displays the last frame

b) Know how to go from any frame (not the first frame) from the last frame

I do not see such methods in the specification for BitmapListAnimation.

Comment: If you set loop to false the OnFinish event will fire. Don't see a way to set the frame so you might need to just use two BitmapListAnimation - one for the first part, then another for the last set to loop. Switch between them in the OnFinish of the first one.